# Tournament cards mucking

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I was playing at a tournament and the following happened: I was playing against another player till the "turn" at which when the opponent saw it he went "all in" which I called. Once I have called him, he stands up, throws his cards away on the table, we still couldn't see them and I don't remember if they have touched the other cards, and walks away. At this time the dealer turns his hands and then the river card. I lost cause he had something better than me. My question is: since he throw the cards like he was mucking and walked away from the table, what happens? Are his cards burnt or can he  still see the river (as it happened)?

Comment: Under tournament rules, a player *may not* fold if he's all in. This is to prevent players from "dumping" chips to a partner. So yes, once he's all in, it's the dealer's job to show the hand and award it the pot, even if he tries to muck it. In a normal live cash game, you would win.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the dealer could retrieve his hand then his hand is live.

A dealer may even go into the muck if he / she is positive which cards were thrown away.

Part of the reason is to avoid chip dumping.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Do you know if it's the same thing in cash game? I guess in cash game his hand is dead, isn't it?

Comment: @yazanpro What ever the cash game decides.

Answer (score 2):

While all-in, you no longer have the option of folding. As long as the dealer is able to ascertain without doubt what his cards are, they are live and he has won the hand. The dealer was correct.